# How to find the flaw in my Codechef solution

Tags: c++, set, c++14

[Link to the questions](https://www.codechef.com/LRNDSA02/problems/NOTALLFL)

The basic question is to find the maximum sub-segment of an array which doesn't have at least one of the k value in the input.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std ;
             
#define ll long long int

void solve()
{
    
      // here the approach is to check from start and keep checking, it take O(n^2) approach but it 
      // should satisfy at least the sub-task but I am getting that too wrong, i.e only one of the
      // two sub-task is getting AC while other WA.
 
    ll i, j, n, k, ans=0, flag=0 ;
    scanf("%lld %lld", &n, &k) ;
    ll a[n+1] ;
    set <int> s ;
    for(i=0 ;i<n ;i++)
    {
        scanf("%lld", &a[i]) ;
    }
    for(i=0 ;i<n ;i++) // this is to start searching for the longest subsegment from start
    {
        s.insert(a[i]) ; // this to keep the count of no. of flavours occuring
        for(j=i+1 ;j<n ;j++) // to continue checking 
        {
            if(s.size()<k && flag==0) 
            {
                s.insert(a[j]) ;
                if(s.size()==k) // if after adding it becomes that condition the size would be one less 
                {
                    ans=max(ans,j-i) ;
                    flag=1 ;
                }
                else
                    ans=max(ans,j-i+1) ;
            }
            else
            {
                s.clear() ;
                break ;
            }
        }
        flag=0 ;
    }
    printf("%lld\n", ans);
}

int main()
{

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false) ;
    cin.tie(NULL) ;
    ll t ;
    scanf("%lld", &t) ;
    while (t--)
    {
        solve() ; // solving no. of test cases
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid embedding critical question-related commentary inside your code.  Imagine you are talking to someone.  Present the information clearly, supplement with code snippets or references to marked sections of code.  Describe what you have tried, including what test cases you have devised to test edge-cases or limits that can make the program fail.

Comment: And from a purely stylistic point of view, _nobody_ puts a space before the semi-colon.  Don't do it.  Read code written by other people, and you will begin to see certain common elements of style.  Adopt some of these into your own style, so others can read your code more easily.  If you are going to add whitespace, there are plenty of more appropriate places to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll take care of it.